# The response object not assign to the variable REDUX-SAGA

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose, redux-saga

I have trouble with the response from the back-end.

I deleted an item with a specific _id using mongoose.

The create method is working well and I can get the value response and assign it into a variable.

Delete is also worked well but I can't get response value to assign the response to variable `const post`

```
function* deletePostSaga(action) {
  try {
    console.log("_id: ", action.payload);
    const post = yield call(api.deletePost, action.payload);
    console.log("Post - Delete: ", post);
    yield put(actions.deletePost.deletePostSuccess(post));
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    yield put(actions.deletePost.deletePostFailure(err));
  }
}
```

The `api.deletePost`:

```
import axios from "axios";

export const fetchPosts = () => axios.get(`/posts`);

export const createPost = (payload) => axios.post(`/posts`, payload);

export const updatePost = (payload) => axios.put("/posts", { data: payload });

export const deletePost = (payload) => {
  console.log(payload);
  axios.delete(`/posts`, { data: payload });
};
```

The item is deleted and I check the network from devtool and check the preview and I also got the response object:

```
message: "Delete successfully"
post: {author: "Anonymous", likeCount: 0, _id: "60d99146df51c152f189b1c4", title: "123", content: "123",…}
attachment: ""
author: "Anonymous"
content: "123"
createdAt: "2021-06-28T09:07:18.178Z"
likeCount: 0
title: "123"
updatedAt: "2021-06-28T09:07:18.178Z"
__v: 0
_id: "60d99146df51c152f189b1c4"
success: true
```

Just don't know why I couldn't assign the response to the `const post` variable, it is just displayed as `undefined`.
Thanks for reading.

Comment: please show `deletePost`

Comment: oh sorry i forgot the important one

Comment: You need to return the data from `deletePost`

Comment: Oh, year you are right I put return before the axios.delete and it returns the value thanks @AshwinR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
deletePost = async (payload) => {
    console.log(payload);
    const response = await axios.delete(`/posts`, { data: payload });
    return response;
};
```

While using `async` key word you need to use `await` in order to make an blocking call.

Answer (score 0):

You need update `deletePost` to return value from `axios`. You can use `async await` like this:

```
deletePost = async (payload) => {
  console.log(payload);
  const response = await axios.delete(`/posts`, { data: payload });
  return response
};
```

Comment: This will return a pending promise. You will not receive the response.

Comment: @AshwinR In this case it doesn't really matter, a promise will be returned anyway. In fact, making the function async does nothing here other than making it more verbose.

Comment: @AsafAviv yes. it does not throw any errors. But it definitely doesn't give you the desired response.

Comment: @AshwinR How exactly? You **have** to call .then or use await when you call this function anyway

Comment: @AsafAviv yes. The above answer did not have either .then or await. So you will not get the desired result

Comment: @AshwinR When you call `deletePost` you have to use .then or await to access the data, the result will be the same.

Comment: @AsafAviv I don't see .then being used in the above question.